# PowerPoint Add-in working on Windows 7 Enterprise edition but not on Windows 7 Pro

Tags: c#, windows-installer, vsto, powerpoint

I have created a PowerPoint add-in using C# VSTO and using msi installer for the deployment.

The Problem is that on every system at my end(all Windows 7 Enterprise edition), the plug-in is working fine, but on users' machines(Windows 7 Pro) either the ribbon is not visible or the events are not working.

My concern is, am I missing something which I need to take care of during the development?
Thanks

Comment: Is the machine running a 64-bit version of Office?

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks for the quick response. I have both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of office. User has 64-bit office version.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons that VSTO deployment is a pain.  You have to understand every dependency of your application and the dependencies of your dependencies and then make sure you cover all of them for every version, flavor and bitness of windows and office that you can think of.  Then you come to find out that a user has a Click To Run version of Office installed that generally doesn't support AddIns anyways.

[VSTO Lessons Learned](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/04/vsto-lessons-learned.html)

[VSTO 4 ( 2010 ) Lessons Learned](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/10/vsto-4-2010-lessons-learned.html)

[Office 2010 Bitness Pain](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/09/office-2010-bitness-pain.html)

There are so many possible failure points in the chain that no one could possibly tell you the cause of your problem.  A lucky guess perhaps but that would be it.  To date I've created VSTO installers for 6 companies and even with my background knowledge and prebuilt templates they are still labor intensive projects because of the test surface that is involved.

Comment: ClickToRun Office 2010 was a dead-end for add-ins.  The CTR version of 2013 doesn't present the same problems.  OTOH, there's the Office on Demand trick and web-only versions of PPT to replace the add-in pain they took away with CTR 2013.

Comment: Great insight Steve. I also remember them giving HKLM addin registration, taking it away and then giving it back. :)  I wish MSFT would make it as easy to deploy addins as it is to develop them.

Comment: And back at you: fantastic resources on the pages you've posted about all this.  Thanks for that.  It makes me realize yet again how happy I am that I decided to stick with VBA for add-in development. ;-)